# How can i send character sequence to a contenteditable="true" element by using selenium and python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

lately, I try to use python3.6 and selenium to do a small task, I want to log in a chatting webpage and send the message automatically.

http://maimai.cn/?regfr=baidu_pc_titlethis is the webpage  that I want to send the message to

In my limited experience with python, I only know that the input element can send string. However, I came across this tough question.
I google a lot and I know that I need to use JavaScript in my python code to insert the string into a div element whose attribute contenteditable is true.
when I run my code like this:

> my_desired_text="lzylzylzy"
>   driver.execute_script("document.getElementsByClassName('inputPanel'[0].innerHTML="+ my_desired_text)

it warns me like that:

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: lzylzylzy is not defined

but I indeed define my string.
I am searching for a long time on the net. But no use, please help or try to give some ideas on how to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my project, there is an iframe element to be located firstly.I locate an element in the iframe but I forget to switch to the main frame.This  element is in the main frame.That is why i can't locate it.If you meet the similar situation, you can check whether you switch to your main frame and use .sendkey() method to send string.